# Convert a date string into YYYYMMDD

Tags: python

I've got a bunch of date strings in this form: -

```
30th November 2009
31st March 2010
30th September 2010
```

I want them like this: -

```
YYYYMMDD
```

Currently I'm doing this: -

```
  parsed_date = "30th November 2009"
  part = parsed_date.split(' ')
  daymonth = part[0].strip(string.ascii_letters)
  mytime = daymonth+" "+part[1]+" "+part[2]
  time_format = "%d %B %Y"
  cdate = time.strptime(mytime, time_format)
  newdate = str(cdate[0])+str(cdate[1])+str(cdate[2])
```

It works, but I'm sure there is a better way...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try [**dateutil**](http://labix.org/python-dateutil):

```
from dateutil import parser

dates = ['30th November 2009', '31st March 2010', '30th September 2010']

for date in dates:
    print parser.parse(date).strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

output:

```
20091130
20100331
20100930
```

or if you want to do it using standard `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = ['30th November 2009', '31st March 2010', '30th September 2010']

for date in dates:
    part = date.split()
    print datetime.strptime('%s %s %s' % (part[0][:-2]), part[1], part[2]), '%d %B %Y').strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Answer (score 6):

You can almost do this with a combination of [`strptime` and `strptime` from the `datetime` module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

The problem we have is that the built-in formats support dates like `30 November 2010` but not `30th November 2010`.  So in the example below I've used [a regular expression substitution](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) to strip out the problem characters.  (The regular expression uses a look-behind to see if "st", "nd", "rd" or "th" is preceeded by a digit, and if so replaces it with the empty string, thus removing it from the string.)

```
>>> import re
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> mydate = "30th November 2009"
>>> mydate = re.sub("(?<=\d)(st|nd|rd|th)","",mydate)
>>> mydate
'30 November 2009'
>>> mydatetime = datetime.strptime(mydate,"%d %B %Y")
>>> mydatetime
datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 30, 0, 0)
>>> mydatetime.strftime("%Y%M%d")
'20090030'
```

Comment: `mydatetime.strftime("%Y%m%d")` is the right way to do it. `%M` is for minutes.

Answer (score 3):

In python 3.7, you can use isoformat()

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.today().date().isoformat().replace("-", "")
'20190220'
```